# ImageInfo of the image file doesn't contain valid values

Tags: java, image, inputstream, dpi, info

I want to get image dpi to convert pixels to cm, so I use ImageInfo.java to get this:

```
ImageInfo myMapInfo = new ImageInfo();
            try {
                File testFile = new File(fileNameString);
                InputStream myMapStream = new FileInputStream(testFile);
                myMapInfo.setInput(myMapStream);
                myMapInfo.setDetermineImageNumber(true);
                myMapInfo.setCollectComments(true);

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            x = myMapInfo.getPhysicalWidthInch();
            y = myMapInfo.getPhysicalHeightInch();
```

but unfortunately I get -1 and -1 in (x, y)! I use this class:
[ImageInfo.java](http://svn.ckeditor.com/FCKeditor.Java/tags/2.4/java-core/src/main/java/org/devlib/schmidt/imageinfo/ImageInfo.java)

Comment: I used sanselan jar library, and it works...

Answer (score 0):

From looking at the source code of ImageInfo, you need to call the `check()` method of your `myMapInfo` variable and if this passes you can use the various `getXxX()` methods to obtain whatever information you need. Incidentally getting -1 as result means information is not available, but that's most likely cause you're not invoking the `check()` method.

Comment: Do you mean to use the `check()` method like: `boolean sth = myMapInfo.check()` ? , I used it and `sth` has a true value but the error remains...

Comment: After you set your input and determineImageNumber etc., you need to call `myMapInfo.check()` . This will try to populate the `myMapInfo` with the available information. You can also try running ImageInfo.java (it has main method and can be used as a console application) directly and supply your test file as input, just to check it works.

Comment: I recognized after testing so, `myMapInfo.getFormatName()` and `myMapInfo.getMimeType()` , ... are working well, but `myMapInfo.getPhysicalWidthInch()` or `myMapInfo.getPhysicalWidthDpi()` returns `-1` !

Comment: Maybe there is something wrong with the image or the library. I would put a break point in the `check()` method and follow through to see where it goes wrong.